# kaltura plugin external resource

Tags: plugins, video-player, kaltura

I am currently making an external plugin for kaltura video player. To embed the plugin in the video player we have set some variables in the flashvars such as:

"flashvars": {
    "myComponent":{
      "plugin":true,
      "iframeHTML5Js" : "plugin.js"
    }
}

I want to place my plugin.js at an external resource such as CDN or through github. Is there any way to do this?

Also, is there a way to reference the plugin code in the page itself without the need of a path to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update it in the studio under ui vars - you can point to a cdn url there.
we dont allow external url from client flashvar configuration